# Unable to select DropDown only for a particular text

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
Select selectresult = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ResultSelect")));

selectresult.selectByVisibleText(ExcelSheet.sh1.getRow(i).getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
```

In the above code value is obtained from excel sheet. If the value is Pass then it's being selected but if its Fail then I'm getting error unable to locate element.

If I provide the value directly as Fail then it is located.

Comment: In that case, try to store the value read from excel in a local variable first and compare it to the expected value - it seems they are different somehow. Perhaps there is some whitespace in one of the values?

Comment: There's space in both the values. Its "Pass All" and "Fail All". I tried comparing also still it fails when the value is "Fail All"

Comment: ExcelSheet.sh1.getRow(i).getCell(1).getStringCellValue() ???? what value is providing... can you show? also any error sample?

Comment: Excel sheet is updated with Pass and Fail in the column 1. i indicates row and iterates till the max. length of the sheet. So, dropdown value is selected based on the excel sheet value at getRow(i).getCell(1).                                                                                     Error  message: 
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate element with text: Fail All

Comment: Excel is error-prone for retrieving text. Use CSV whenever possible. I once had an issue with non-breaking space characters (U+00A0). There might be invisible characters or weird line-breaks as well.  I would this for quick debugging `System.out.println("[" + ExcelSheet.sh1.getRow(i).getCell(1).getStringCellValue() + "]");`

Comment: [Fail All
]    this is the output. Vale is retrieved from excel but when it is passed in select I'm getting error